# how to deal with trailing blanks after importing from excel to sas

Tags: excel, import, sas

I can find several topics and solutions on importing from excel to SAS and how to deal with *variable names* containing blanks or spaces.

However, in my situation, some of the *variable values* contain spaces at the end, and after importing I can see the trailing blanks, but compress does not remove them.

I'm thinking they're some other type of character. I've tried some modifiers on the compress function, but cannot seem to make it recognize these spaces.

Because I'm often creating different excel files, I would prefer not having to remove the blanks manually. Is there an option to the proc import step I should add, or is there a modifier I can provide to the compress function to solve this?

I'm using the following basic code to import:

```
proc import out      = METADATA
            datafile = "&mdata\meta_data.xlsx"
            DBMS     = Excel replace;
            SHEET    = "Sheet1";
            GETNAMES = YES;
run;
```

EDIT (after implementing instructions from comments):

I don't really know how my component of SAS is called - I started working with SAS recently.
I'm using some kind of editor, with a VIEWTABLE window. When looking at my dataset this way, I can select (as in highlight) the variable values. One of my values has a trailing whitespace - I can highlight a finite space beyond the string, which I can't for the other variables. And I know the space is there because I have put it there in excel as well.

The length of my variable is 8, and setting the format to $HEX128 shows:

DOSE 444F534520202020

DOSE2 444F534532A02020

DOSE2 contains the blank space so it's actually 'DOSE2 ' in excel and in the VIEWTABLE.
When converting from string to hex I believe '2' is converted to 32.
That means the whitespace is converted to 'A0' instead of '20'.

Comment: SAS does not support meaningful trailing spaces in values because everything is stored as fixed length strings that are padded with spaces.  So there should be no need to remove any trailing spaces.

Comment: Can you explain how you 'can see the trailing blanks' ?  What are the attributes of the character variables (such as length) ?  If you think you have non-space whitespace trailing characters you can change the format of the column in the viewer to something like $HEX128. to see the hex codes of the first 64 characters in the value -- if the trailing values with this format are `202020`.that is normal space padding to variable length behavior of base SAS data sets.  NOTE: The functions `LENGTH ` `LENGTHM` and `LENGTHC` deal with different concepts of character length

Comment: @Richard I've followed your instructions. I do believe it's a different kind of whitespace, please see the edits in my question.

Comment: @Richard I've found out this is a non-breaking space - using this keyword in further searches I could find a solution. I should use y=compress(y, 'A0'x). Thank you for your suggestions on how to find out what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference for other people searching on these keywords or this topic:

After importing from excel where your values contain spaces, you might end up with a special kind of whitespace: these are non-breaking spaces. 
You can find out by setting the format to $HEX128. - the whitespaces should be converted to A0 instead of 20, used for regular whitespaces.

If you want to remove these, you can use var = compress(var, 'A0'x);